# Algorithm to list all combinations from a table where data is present or NULL

Tags: python, combinations, combinatorics

I have an Excel file (which can optionally be loaded into a database, and into an array of arrays of course) with values such as:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | zxy |
| xyz | xzy | NULL |
| xyz | xzy | xyy |
| yzy | yyx | yxy |
| NULL | NULL | xyx |
| xyz | NULL | yxx |

and so on.

There are thousands of values.

Is there any known algorithm to come up with all possible combinations of rows where values are not "NULL"?

For example for the table above the result would be:

| A | B | C | Number of occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | * | 2 |
| * | * | NULL | 1 |
| * | * | * | 2 |
| * | NULL | * | 1 |

I feel like it is a typical task, but cannot find the algorithm anywhere. Would appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are tempted to use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")

out = (
    df.replace(".+", "*", regex=True).fillna("NULL")
        .groupby(list(df), group_keys=False, sort=False)
        .size().reset_index(name="Number of occurrences")
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)
    
      A     B     C  Number of occurrences
0  NULL  NULL     *                      2
1     *     *  NULL                      1
2     *     *     *                      2
3     *  NULL     *                      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working approach, after loading your data into an array of tuples; first I normalize all non NULL values to '*', then using a `Counter` does the job:

```
data = [
        ('NULL','NULL', 'zxy'),
        ('xyz', 'xyz', 'NULL'),
        ('xyz', 'xzy', 'xyy'),
        ('yzy', 'yyx', 'yxy'),
        ('NULL','NULL', 'xyx'),
        ('xyz', 'NULL', 'yxx')
        ]

def normalize(tup):
    return tuple(el if el == 'NULL' else '*' for el in tup)

from collections import Counter

stats = Counter(map(normalize, data))

# Counter({('NULL', 'NULL', '*'): 2,
           ('*', '*', 'NULL'): 1,
           ('*', '*', '*'): 2,
           ('*', 'NULL', '*'): 1})
```